# Setting magento voucher rules on the admin backend

Tags: magento-1.7

basically if a user has added two products on cart he is allowed to add two vouchers, and i've done that part but when a product that was added on basket has been removed by the user the voucher still exist on cart. can i use voucher rules to solve this problem?

```
 public function deleteAction()
{

    $products = 2;
    // $vouchers_added = 2;
    $quote_id = (int)$this->getRequest()->getParam('id');
    $voucher = Mage::getModel('healthystart/voucher')->load($quote_id);
    if ($quote_id) {
        if  ($products === $voucher){
            $this->addErrorMessage('good.');
            return;
        }
        else {
            if($voucher < $products){
                $this->addErrorMessage('Remove a voucher please.');
                $this->_goBack();
            }
        }

        parent::deleteAction();
    }
}
```

Comment: Some more information is required in order to help you, such as what voucher extension are you using, what event(s) are you listening to, show us some code?

Comment: hi, that is the code that I thought it will work, but is does 20% of what I want it to do.

Comment: Any movement on this? Anything I can do to help clarify an answer for you? Please update your question if you have more information that can help us close this out.

Answer (score 1):

The list of potential issues with your specific problem go well beyond the scope of this question. For instance, there should be no reason to be rewriting a controller's action based on what you show here. But for the sake of helping you debug and putting you on the right path, consider the following:

**Comparison:**

In this context, `$voucher` is an object of type Healthystart_Model_Voucher. You are **comparing it to an integer**, `$products`. They will never be equivalent.

**Schema:**

Your use of `Mage::getModel('healthystart/voucher')->load()` suggests that you only expect one voucher model back. However, unless this is enforced by the schema of the storage engine, any number of results could be returned when loading a voucher by the quote id.

In that case, you probably would only ever get the first item and thus the voucher count will always be one.

**Optimization:**

- This line: `$quote_id = (int)$this->getRequest()->getParam('id')` casts a potential `null` if no param named ID exists to an int - if you cast `null` to an int, it will return 0. Because there is no `else` condition on your outer else, this action will do nothing and return a blank page. Is this intentional?
- You don't need `$voucher` unless `if($quote_id)` evaluates to `true` - in that case, you shouldn't load it outside the `if` - it's unnecessary.
- You are calling `parent::deleteAction()` only when there is a valid `$quote_id`; is this intentional?

**Conclusion:**

There is not enough information to help you with your actual problem. Hopefully the above points will lead you to your eventual solution.

HTH, Cheers.